# On the cauchy sequence $x^n$ in $(C[0,1],\|\cdot\|_\infty)$

Tags: cauchy-sequences

I know how to prove that $x^n$ is not cauchy in $(C[0,1],\|\cdot\|_\infty)$, but my question is that since $(C[0,1],\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ is complete, and the pointwise limit on $x^n$ is:

$x^n\to f(x) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
         1 & \mbox{if $x =1$};\\
        0 & \mbox{if $0\le x \lt 1 $}.\end{array} \right.  $

And this limit is not continuous, and thus is not in $C[0,1]$.

So if the sequence were cauchy then the limit would exist in $C[0,1]$ (by completeness), so isn't that an instant contradiction? Meaning no formal proof is necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are absolutely correct. But proving that $C[0,1]$ is complete with respect to $L_\infty$ norm is at least a little bit non-trivial.

Comment: Oh definitely, it's just little things like this really help in exams!